# Блок на css

Tags: css

Как сделать блок на css чтоб он был в верхней части сайта 100% шириной и что бы не было пробелов? 
Цвет: #505050;
ширина: 100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не помню точно, но наверно так:
.mydiv {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #505050;
}
Если не поможет с пробелами, попробуй еще так добавить:
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

Comment: Да, работает. Вставить надо оба блока кода.

Comment: Странно, у меня работает. Я заменил margin: 0; на margin: 16px 0 0 0;
 и добавил height: 50px; в класс .mydiv.

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб текст был по середине блока получается. Вот скрипт стиля текста: 

`
.txt-logo {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-left: 6%;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}
` 

Но он не ставиться по центру и margin-left перестает работать http://prntscr.com/2qmuz4

Comment: margin-left перестает работать, потому что margin стоит после него и обнуляет его значение. Поменяйте их местами, хотя бы. А лучше напишите margin: 16px 0 0 6%;
Далее, text-align: center; надо указывать блочным элементам, а точнее классу header. И еще, для этого же класса поизменяйте padding, чтобы изменить вертикальное расположение текста.

Comment: Свойство text-align уберите из класса .txt-logo в класс .header. Далее, margin-left, которые стоит до margin, не оказывает никакого влияния. Или поменяйте их местами, или уберите один из них. И наконец добавьте в .header свойство padding: 15px; и ваш текст сместится вниз. Плюс, почитайте на htmlbook.ru про свойство position, тоже пригодится.

P.S padding-top: _px; установи отступ сверху и уменьши height у .header и будет счастье. Описание всех атрибутов на htmlbook.ru

Comment: А как сделать, чтоб по центру выравнивался текст в css margin-top: 50%; Не считается

align я убрал вообще, потому что я через margin-left сместил текст.
padding: 15 сделал блок стал по высоте больше, мне не надо большой. 

Вот так правильно? http://prntscr.com/2qn6qx

Comment: Ладно уж. Оставлю как есть, не получаеться чет вообще ни как, почитаю сам разберусь потом. Спасибо.