# Как спустить текст вниз?

Tags: css

Скрипт написан здесь [Блок на css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295438/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css)
Я вставил туда ссылку и у меня щас пробелма. Я сделал этот блок высотой 50px и щас мне надо опустить на 16px. Я сделал margin-top: 16px; но не работает. (header - это тот самый стиль блока; txt-logo - стили текста)

```
<div class="header"><a href="/" class="txt-logo">GamesFaceBook</a></div>
```

Как мне опустить текст вниз?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам требуется получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.txt-logo {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
font-size: 26px;
margin-left: 6%; // зачем если все равно обнуляете в конце?
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 16px; // может это вам надо?
}
```

Comment: Не работает, но я уже решил оставить так как есть.

Comment: Оставил вот такой скрипт: 


`
.txt-logo {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-left: 6%;
 text-decoration: none;
}
`

Comment: @cnofss, а с каких пор код CSS называется скриптом? Может это какие-то новые веяния в верстке, а я и не знал ...:-)

Comment: Ну что вам конкретно надо вниз опустить? Текст ссылки? Если да, то может вам попробовать отдельное правило для ссылки?

    .txt_logo a {
        display: block;
        margin:16px auto 0 auto;
    }

Comment: Вот этот вариант работает :D

Comment: @Astor я написал скрипт? Извините, ошибся.

Comment: @cnofss, ничего ... бывает!

Answer (score 0):

Margin не сработал по причине того что тег a является inline он по умолчанию не может двигаться вверх или вниз ОТСТУПАМИ.

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, если хотим сделать отступ сверху нужно чтобы элемент перестал быть inline. Например так:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 100px;
```

Так же мы можем позиционировать элемент относительно экрана/родителя/своего места в DOM. с помощью (пример позиционирования элемента относительно родителя, у родителя тоже должен быть position: relative):

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 5px;
```

Так же мы можем сдвинуть элемент с помощью трансформаций например(сдвинуть по Y Элемент относительно своего места в DOM):

```
transform: translateY(-50px);
```